# How to find the content-length of Page <Entity> to be passed as the http header?

Tags: java, spring-boot, netflix-eureka, netflix-zuul

I am using spring boot along with Netflix Eureka. I need to find the total length of Page to set the content-length in the HTTP response header.
My controller is like this
...

```
Page<exampleEntity> examplePage = null;
examplePage=exampleService.getFuntion(request, params);
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setContentLength(???);
return new ResponseEntity<>(Page, HttpHeaders ,HttpStatus.OK);
```

...

could anyone please help?

Comment: Any reason you want to set this value at all? Shouldn't Spring take care of that?

Comment: it is not setting it by default or am I unaware of the default settings I can provide?

Comment: You're right. Spring currently adds the "Transfer-Encoding" header instead. You could look into `ShallowETagHeaderFilter`. See https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/21263

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ObjectOutputStream out = null;
try {
  out = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);   
  out.writeObject(yourObject);
  out.flush();
  byte[] yourBytes = bos.toByteArray();
  
} finally {
  try {
    bos.close();
  } catch (IOException ex) {
    // ignore close exception
  }
}
```

Then yourBytes.length is what you need

Comment: the code worked for me thanks a lot for that, but one thing is when I tried to call that method in postman it returned the required response after few mins(which is not normal because it would take only few seconds) but response code was 400 instead of 200, and also there was no issue with test unit, is this postman specific issue?

Comment: You should create a new question and provide information such as log, code snippet, context, etc